# Predection Engine - schema mismatch: "expected scalar or known-size vector of R4, got variable-size vector"

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I am trying to train and predict a model with multiple features. We'll call my data "Histogram", with a floating point Target, and `Sensor1` through to `Sensor6` which are `float[64]`.

The data is loaded from a CSV with the first column as the Target, and then columns 1-64 Sensor1, 65-129 Sensor2, etc.

The Histogram class:

```
class Histogram
{
    [LoadColumn(0)] public float Target;
    [LoadColumn(1, 64), ColumnName("Sensor1")]
    public float[] Sensor1;
    [LoadColumn(65, 129), ColumnName("Sensor2")]
    public float[] Sensor2;
    [LoadColumn(130, 193), ColumnName("Sensor3")]
    public float[] Sensor3;
    [LoadColumn(194, 257), ColumnName("Sensor4")]
    public float[] Sensor4;
    [LoadColumn(258, 321), ColumnName("Sensor5")]
    public float[] Sensor5;
    [LoadColumn(322, 385), ColumnName("Sensor6")]
    public float[] Sensor6;
}
```

The training completes, but when creating a prediction engine with:

```
var predictor = trainedModel.CreatePredictionEngine<Histogram, PredictedTarget>(mlCtx);
```

it throws this exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for input column 'Sensor1': expected scalar or known-size vector of R4, got variable-size vector
Parameter name: inputSchema'
```

I am creating the processing pipeline as:

```
IDataView baseTrainingDataView = mlCtx.Data.LoadFromTextFile<Histogram>(trainDataPath, hasHeader: true, separatorChar: ',');
var dataProcessPipeline = mlCtx.Transforms
            .CopyColumns(DefaultColumnNames.Label, nameof(Histogram.Target))
            .Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Normalize(nameof(Histogram.Sensor1), "Sensor1"))
            .Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Normalize(nameof(Histogram.Sensor2), "Sensor2"))
            .Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Normalize(nameof(Histogram.Sensor3), "Sensor3"))
            .Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Normalize(nameof(Histogram.Sensor4), "Sensor4"))
            .Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Normalize(nameof(Histogram.Sensor5), "Sensor5"))
            .Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Normalize(nameof(Histogram.Sensor6), "Sensor6"))
            .Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Concatenate(DefaultColumnNames.Features, "Sensor1", "Sensor2", "Sensor3", "Sensor4", "Sensor5", "Sensor6"));
```

I'm actually unsure what more information to provide, because it's my first try with ML.NET. I'll edit in more as needed! Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code that reads from the file?

Comment: @Jon, the `mlCtx.Data.LoadFromTextFile` is supplied with the CSV file `trainDataPath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most ML.NET trainers expect fixed size vectors.
You can use the VectorType attribute to specify the feature is a vector. Here's how your Histogram class will look with the VectorType attribute decoration.

```
class Histogram
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public float Target;

    [LoadColumn(1, 64), ColumnName("Sensor1"), VectorType(64)]
    public float[] Sensor1;

    [LoadColumn(65, 129), ColumnName("Sensor2"), VectorType(64)]
    public float[] Sensor2;

    [LoadColumn(130, 193), ColumnName("Sensor3"), VectorType(64)]
    public float[] Sensor3;

    [LoadColumn(194, 257), ColumnName("Sensor4"), VectorType(64)]
    public float[] Sensor4;

    [LoadColumn(258, 321), ColumnName("Sensor5"), VectorType(64)]
    public float[] Sensor5;

    [LoadColumn(322, 385), ColumnName("Sensor6"), VectorType(64)]
    public float[] Sensor6;
}
```

Also, the Normalize() method's signature is Normalize(outputColumnName, inputColumnName). Although it may not matter in this case because the input column name and output column names resolve to the same values (eg: Sensor1), it might be safer to include the parameter names in the invocation as there are multiple overloads of Normalize() with default parameters. Although verbose, including the parameter names explicitly makes your intention clear.

```
...
.Append(mlCtx.Transforms.Normalize(outputColumnName: "Sensor1",
                                   inputColumnName: nameof(Histogram.Sensor1)))
...
```

Comment: This has helped get past the line it was previously having an exception! However, now `predictor.Predict(sample)` is having a runtime exception. But you have earned the bounty, regardless!

Comment: @Patrick, what is the error you are getting? It is most likely a Schema comprehension issue with the PredictedTarget class. Do you have the [ColumnName("Score")] attribute decoration on the class property in your PredictedTarget class that holds the value of the regression?

Comment: @wgiri, I'm using the same `Histogram` class, populating everything except `Target` - leaving it as zero. The exception is `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'`

Comment: Could you post the definition of your PredictedTarget class?